# Java Killswitch

Tags: java

I've created a java application I'm selling for money, and the verification system involves using an unique HWID to ID the computer to see if they've paid. I was wondering if there was a way for a java application to "kill" itself, maybe deleting some of it's own class files, corrupting itself, or overriding itself.

Is there any way?

Comment: If your application is worth pirating, don't expect this to work for very long.

Comment: Somehow I see this hurting your paying customers more than the pirates.

Answer (score 3):

Make it web based, keep records in the database, make the user log in to use the system.  Any dedicated cracker will defeat your system in a matter of time.

Comment: what if the app needs to be run locally?. If this is a commercial grade app, then I would recommend using a security solution designed by professionals. Security and Cryptography is best left to experts.

Comment: I am not here to provide security advice, I am looking at it from the practical side of things.  Also, unless you know someone's education you should be less condescending.

Comment: Sorry about that. The second line was not addressed at you and should have been inside my post. Edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a commercial grade app, then I would recommend using a security solution designed by professionals. Security and Cryptography is best left to experts

Layman solution :
Could you execute a [getmac](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff961509%28WS.10%29.aspx) (assuming this app runs out of windows) from within your system and do the check.? MAC ids are assumed to be unique for a PC. There are ways to override it but should address 90% of the cases.

Corrupting your app doesn't seem to be a good solution.

Comment: So when I replace my failing wireless card and the MAC address changes, I'm locked out of the application?

Comment: how often do you do that :) . You need to get a better laptop then :P . Jokes aside, as I told this is not a great solution. What I would recommend as I have told before is get an industry vetted security layer protecting your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static String getURLSource(String link) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(link);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(inputLine);
                }
                reader.close();
                return str.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't properly connect to internet.");
            }
        }

  public void main(String[] args) {
          if(!getUrlSource("yourlink").contains("a string you want when it's not killswitched")) { //The link must be readable text by java
               //Do stuff here
          }
}
```